# JS height adjustment should work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using some JS code to automatically adjust the height of the buttons when the slideshow is smaller due to screen size. It works when used in the Chrome console, but fails when inserted into the site.

Site: http://www.incensu.co.uk/

You can see where I'm placing the code as it's commented out at the bottom of /js/main.js and here it is for reference:

```
var homeTopMain = $('#homeTopMain');
if (homeTopMain) {
  var btnHeight = (homeTopMain.height()+20)/3-20; // 20px at bottom, 3 buttons, 20px between.
  $('.btnFlapsBodyWrapper').height(btnHeight);
  $('.btnFlapsRed').height(btnHeight);
  $('.btnFlapsGrey').height(btnHeight);
}
```

I'm thinking that perhaps it's the the timing of the code or a scoping issue, but I'm just not seeing it for some reason. Perhaps someone with a clear mind could spot the problem?

Comment: It looks like you need to move it so that it comes after your flexslider scripting.

Comment: @rnirnber, unless I'm mistaken JS also uses the standard operator ordering of multiplication and division happening before subtraction and addition.

Comment: @Zak, well spotted, thanks. Moving it above in the DOM doesn't guarantee one ready() will happen after another completes, so I've moved my code into a window.load call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zak's tip pointed me in the right direction. Moving it above in the DOM doesn't guarantee one ready() will happen after another completes. The correct solution is remove the code from the $(document).ready() block and place it in a $(window).load() block.

Answer (score -1):

You could resize the button when DOM is ready and also execute when window is resizing.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function ResizeButton()
    {
        var homeTopMain = $('#homeTopMain');
        if (homeTopMain) {
          var btnHeight = (homeTopMain.height()+20)/3-20; // 20px at bottom, 3 buttons, 20px between.
          $('.btnFlapsBodyWrapper').height(btnHeight);
          $('.btnFlapsRed').height(btnHeight);
          $('.btnFlapsGrey').height(btnHeight);
        }
    }
    ResizeButton();
    $(window).resize(ResizeButton);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't address the original question.